# ASP NET Override authorize attribute with another for a specific action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

In ASP NET  I want to apply

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

to a controller, but to a specific action inside it I want only the requirement is to 
be authenticated, so I would apply only the

```
 [Authorize]
```

, but this
does not seem to override the controller attribute.

Comment: Why not put the lowest level of privilege on the controller and the elevated level of privilege on the action?

Comment: @George presumably the issue is that there could a lot of methods that would need it adding to

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree, however, rearranging attributes and annotating his actions would most likely be *less work* than rolling a custom solution only to break an understood convention.

Comment: What if you did [Authorize(Roles="")] on your Action method?

Comment: @Rob That does not seem to work. So the best practice is what George said ?

Comment: Yes, you have to apply the least restrictive attribute at the controller level. But, there's another solution here: 
http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.ca/2011/04/default-authorization-filter-provider.html